# Android studio installation folder not recognize

Tags: android-studio, installation-path

Android studio v4.2.1 installation folder not recognize when I select Help -> Edit Custom VM Options...
it show below path.

[image]

Whereas my Android Studio installed in C:\Android\Android Studio.
I set **STUDIO_VM_OPTIONS**=C:\Android\Android Studio\bin but not working.

Comment: What did come when you create ?

Comment: @HimeshPerera it create studio64.exe.vmoptions at that location.

Comment: How about using the file created at that location?  instead of modifying the path to C:\Android\Android Studio\bin ?

Comment: I didn't modify any thing in that. What I modify so that I come to know that changes are taking or not.

Comment: 1. Did you see if there are any STUDIO_VM_OPTIONS already configured above the line where you mentioned STUDIO_VM_OPTIONS=C:\Android\Android Studio\bin in the environment? 

2. Are you running the program as Administrator (or) does the error pop up even in Admin mode?

3. Can you check if PATH variable contains the binaries directory? and does the studi64.exe.vmoptions exits at STUDIO_VM_OPTIONS?

Comment: There is no STUDIO_VM_OPTIONS set except I added to STUDIO_VM_OPTIONS=C:\Android\Android Studio\bin. I run the program in Admin mode. studi64.exe.vmoptions exist at C:\Android\Android Studio\bin.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are not installing Android Studio to the default location path which is :  C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio, and the Android SDK should be installed at : C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk.

Check out this URL for guidance : [https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/android/Android_HowTo.html#:~:text=by%20default%2C%20the%20%22Android%20Studio,Local%5CAndroid%5CSdk%20%22](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/android/Android_HowTo.html#:%7E:text=by%20default%2C%20the%20%22Android%20Studio,Local%5CAndroid%5CSdk%20%22).

Try to re-install your Android Studio using the default options and paths.

Comment: I don't want to re-install Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the file studio64.exe.vmoptions from the following path:

`C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin`

to

`C:\Users\home\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio4.2`

Answer (score 0):

Move your Android Studio folder to `C:\Users\your.username\Android-Studio` and retry

Sometimes cmd not recognize your file location , maybe permissions or other thinks.